# How To Pass a Groovy Array to Shell Script in Jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, groovyshell

I need to get the array that I have in my groovy Script and pass it shell Script for further Calculation in the Shell Script

I have tried multiple was but I am not getting the array passed to Shell Script.

```
templates = ["Temp1","Temp2","Temp3"]
templateCount = templates.size()
sh """
  count = ${templateCount} 
  temp = ${templates}
  for (( i=0; i < count; i++ ))
  do
    echo "Template Name = " ${temp[i]}
   done
"""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try one of the following options.

```
script {
    def templates = ["Temp1","Temp2","Temp3"]
    sh """
        for v in ${templates.join(' ')}
        do
            echo \$v
        done
    """

    // Option 2
    for(tmp in templates) {
        sh "echo ${tmp}"
    }
}
```